# Onclick invokes function with increased argument value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, button

I have a jQuery function which takes an argument (let's say arg) which is a number.

I also have a button which invokes the function when the button is clicked.

How can I get the button to invoke the function with an increasing arg number with each click?

E.g. first button click invokes `myFunction(1)`,second button click invokes `myFunction(2)`, etc.

I want the button click to invoke `myFunction(arg)`, where `arg` is the number of click.

`myFunction` itself isn't a counter, it does it's own code.

html:

```
<button  id='newData' value=0 onclick='sinAjax()'>New Data</button>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    setValue();
    $('#newData').onclick('click', setValue);
});

function setValue()
{
    var val = parseInt($('#newData').val());
    var newVal = val +=100;
    $('#newData').val(newVal);
}
```

I want to invoke `sinAjax( click number+100 )` on each click

Updated code:

html:

```
<button  id='newData' value=0 >New Data</button>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    setValue();
    $('#newData').click( function () {
        sinAjax(val);
    }) ;    
}) ;  

function setValue() {
    val = parseInt($('#newData').val());
    var newVal = val +=100;
    $('#newData').val(newVal);
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that the button only works once, then successive clicks give me the same values.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. SO questions are expected to show [search and research](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: with respect - that edited code is from the code that I posted as a solution - but you have modified it. It is extremely best NOT to have inline script (eg:the onclick you have added to the button) since you have jQuery and event handlers. Far better to modify the function that i had and since there was already an event handler to trigger the function - you wdo not need the inline onclick handler.

Comment: The only changes needed to your original code to get it to work are (a) bind the jQuery click handler properly: `$('#newData').click(setValue);` and then (b) call `sinAjax(newVal)` from within your `setValue()` function, and (c) remove the inline `onclick` attribute.

Comment: thanks, i've made the changes that you have suggested and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to accomplish this task: storing the increasing value into a data-attr attribute or, just:

```
var counter = 0;
$(element).on('click', function() {
  myFunction(counter++);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of the button to 0 (or use a data atttribute) , get the function to get the value of the button., increment it and then set the the value to the new value. That way it doesn't matter whether you trigger the function programmtically or via the click - the action is the same

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 setValue();
 $("#myButton").on('click',setValue)
   })
 
 function setValue(){
   var val = parseInt($("#myButton").val());
   var newVal = val += 1;
   $("#myButton").val(newVal)
   console.log("New Value is: " + newVal)
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type ="button" value="0" id="myButton">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button clickTime="1" onclick="myFunction(this.getAttribute('clickTime'),this)">遁地龙卷风</button>
function myFunction(time,target)
{
    alert(time)
    target.setAttribute('clickTime',+time+1)
}
```